Extensions by scalars along Frobenius
My question probably just needs the knowledge of some commutative algebra but it is ultimately motivated from the theory of formal groups in chromatic homotopy theory.
Question. Let $R$ be an $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra and $\operatorname{Frob}_R : R \to R, \ r \mapsto r^p$. Is $$R \otimes_{R, \mathrm{Frob}_R} R [[x ]] \cong R [[x]]$$ (as topological rings with the $(x)$-adic topology)?
If it's easier, feel free to deal with polynomial rings and just rings (without a topology) - I'm not sure how relevant that is.
This would show $\operatorname{Spf}(R \otimes_R R [[x ]]) \cong \operatorname{Spf}(R [[x ]])$ which has to do with the relative Frobenius and is claimed in Example 13.2 of Piotr's Finite Height Chromatic Homotopy Theory.
If $R$ has some additional properties, like being a perfect field over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or so, then I would be fine with it. But right now it looks like the tensor product is isomorphic to $R^p[[x^p]]$ which should not be isomorphic to $R[[x]]$ in general. So possibly some details about the topology are relevant...?

I would guess this is false, unless you assume (at least) that $R$ is perfect. Do you have a reason to believe this?

@AlexYoucis I would guess so as well. The reason for this question is Example 13.2 in Piotr‘s notes as linked in the question!

I mean, I guess it's OK, in the sense that you aren't requiring that the structure map to $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be preserved (which I missed before). Namely, I assume you mean the $x$-adically completed tensor product (which when you're taking fiber product of formal spectra is what you want), then I guess that $R\widehat{\otimes}_{R,\mathrm{Frob}R}R[![x]!]\simeq (R\otimes{R,\mathrm{Frob}R}R)[![x]!]$. But, as abstract rings one has that $R\otimes{R,\mathrm{Frob}_R}R\simeq R$ (but not as $R$-algebras).

@AlexYoucis Sounds good, thank you! Feel free to post an answer with this content if you like.

This does hold true with the (presumably intended) $x$-adically completed tensor product. Namely,
$$R\widehat{\otimes}_{R,\mathrm{Frob}_R}R[\![x]\!]\simeq (R\otimes_{R,\mathrm{Frob}_R}R)[\![x]\!])\simeq R[\![x]\!],$$
as adic $\mathbb{Z}[\![x]\!]$-algebras. Indeed, the first point is evident by passing to the limit over $n$ of the isomorphism
$$R\otimes_{R,\mathrm{Frob}_R}(R[x]/x^n)\simeq (R\otimes_{R,\mathrm{Frob}_R}R)[x]/x^n,$$
and the latter because $R\otimes_{R,\mathrm{Frob}_R}R$ is isomorphic to $R$ as a ring (not as an $R$-algebra).
